# python convert from unknown format

Tags: python, format

I am using python to convert a rtf file to plain text.  I am using [pyth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/0.5.4) to convert it, but it ends up in a format that I don't recognize.

Here is my input python script:

```
from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
from pyth.plugins.plaintext.writer import PlaintextWriter
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    filename = "C:\localdata\logbook.rtf"

doc = Rtf15Reader.read(open(filename, "rb"))

y = [x.content for x in doc.content]
for j in y:
    print j
```

Here is what the ouput looks like:

```
[Text('[AJAJ]' {})]
[Text('[07:30 - Setup IP address]' {})]
[Text('[copied DM Queue and recipies from AYT404]' {})]
[Text('[07:50 - Backed up system pre SP7]' {})]
[Text('[08:00 - Installing SP7]' {})]
[Text('[08:15 - Startup Drivers -> OK]' {})]
```

Does anyone know what format this is and how can I convert this to something more readable?

Comment: This is perfectly readable for me. What exactly did you expect the output to look like?

Comment: After reading the doc, try: `print PlaintextWriter.write(doc).getvalue()`

Comment: I am trying to parse only the text out of the rtf file to reduce the filesize, when i use the PlaintextWriter it seems to convert the images to a lot of unreadable data and does not reduce the size.

Comment: @WorldSEnder You are correct it is readable, but I want the [Text('[AJAJ]' {})] to be turned into simply AJAJ

Comment: Why not just write a quick filter to get what you want?  From the sample you've posted, it looks like you just have to drop the first 8 characters and the last 7 characters (if I've counted correctly).  So instead of `print j` you'd have `print j[8:-7]`

Comment: The returned `doc` is built out of the objects documented here: http://pydoc.net/Python/pyth/0.5.6/pyth.document/ - apart from literal strings. You'd need a recursive approach to actually print anything meaningful (given that arbitrary documents are possible). How are you expecting that to be printed? Or just do what Carl proposed

Comment: I am trying to reduce the filesize, when I use the PlaintextWriter it does not reduce the file, even though it changes it from rtf to txt.  @saulspatz when i try using that method each line returns only []

Comment: @clayton33 Okay, please try `print str(j)[8:-7]`  I'm not familiar with these modules, and I assumed you had strings, but this should work.  `str(j)` should be the string representation that is getting printed, so we grab it and modify it before printing.

Comment: I think due to my lack of python knowledge I am missing something simple.  @saulspatz Change your comment to an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier just to write a simple filter to get what you want.  From the sample you've posted, it looks like you just have to drop the first 8 characters and the last 7 characters (if I've counted correctly). So instead of `print j` you'd have

```
print str(j)[8:-7]
```

The reason you need the `str` is that the object is the list `y` are apparently not strings.  I'm not familiar with these modules, so I can't say what kind of objects they are, but their string representation is what we see printed.  (Every python object has a string representation of some sort, which is why you can call `print` on anything.)  So, whatever kind of object j actually is, `str(j)` is its string representation, and we can slice it.